# Reading and decoding PDF-417 barcodes stored in an image or PDF file from within a .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, barcode, decode

I am looking for a .NET library that is able to decode data from a [PDF-417 barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417) that is embedded either in an image file or PDF.  At this point, I have only been able to find a [Java version](http://turbulence.org/Works/swipe/barcode.html) and a [C version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf417decode/).

Ideally, this library would be both open-source and free of charge, but I doubt such a decoder exists.

I am open to trying out demos of existing products that you may have had experience with - which leads me to the question - have you had any experience reading PDF-417 barcodes embedded in images or PDFs using .NET, and which of the available products would you recommend to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use components (not free) from [IDAutomation](http://www.idautomation.com) for PDF417.  They are very good.  We use them for encoding, as opposed to reading and decoding.

Haven't used this component of theirs, but have a look it is C#, and you can obtain the source code, but again, not free.

http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-recognition/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking at this earlier but I wasn't able to find a decoder for PDF417 on that site without the Unlimited Developer License. It's looking like it's going to be a lot cheaper just to buy a physical scanner and use that on the items before they're scanned in!

Comment: Update: the link indicates that the component has been discontinued.  IDAutomation's current barcode components all seem to address generation rather than decoding.

Answer (score 4):

The [ClearImage Barcode Recognition SDK for .NET](http://www.inliteresearch.com/barcode-recognition/) is probably the easiest way to decode PDF 417 and many other barcodes. I use it in many projects... although it is not free

```
         var bitmap = WpfImageHelper.ConvertToBitmap(_BarcodeCam.BitmapSource);

        _ImageEditor.Bitmap = bitmap;
        _ImageEditor.AutoDeskew();
        _ImageEditor.AdvancedBinarize();

        var reader = new BarcodeReader();
        reader.Horizontal = true;
        reader.Vertical = true;
        reader.Pdf417 = true;

        //_ImageEditor.Bitmap.Save("c:\\barcodeimage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        var barcodes = reader.Read(_ImageEditor.Bitmap);

        if (barcodes.Count() > 0)
```

Comment: I put this library behind a web service and sent it cropped and scaled images of PDF417 barcodes (~40K JPEGs) from an iPad camera.  As long as the images were in focus and had reasonable lighting levels it did a good job.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://platform.twit88.com/projects/mt-barcode

This is a zxing c# port

Comment: Fixed the link, but compared to the ClearImage library this is hopeless.  I couldn't get it to recognise any images, whereas the ClearImage library had a very good success rate.

Comment: is this a library file

Comment: I implemented this but it was highly sensitive and required crystal clear barcodes that were cropped already.  I went with another ZXing port instead: https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net

Answer (score 1):

I've just successfully integrated the ZXing .Net port from java.  It's not as powerful as other paid SDK's - for instance it couldn't detect barcodes in a rotated image.  However, it's free and might work for you if you're on a budget.  Generally you'll find the paid SDKs cost $400 and up.  It has over a million downloads on Nuget, if that means anything.

https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net

Answer (score 0):

Aspose has a PDF417 encoder/decoder for both .NET and Java, but it is not open source: http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.barcode-for-.net/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Morovia provides a free [pdf417 decoder](http://forums.morovia.com/free-pdf417-decoder-pdf417decode-t231.html).

Comment: This isn't a library, it's an executable.  Also, it's only free for personal use.