# Decoding Barcode Image in C#

Tags: c#, barcode, decode

Has anybody been able to use the barcode decoding application given on the following link? I am unable to run the application.

Reference Link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeImaging3.aspx

I downloaded the source code and added its reference into my project.
When I debug the code in VS 2008, it shows me a pop-up containing:

> The following module was built with
>   optimizations enabled or without debug
>   information :
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\7c06d97f\c871fca3\assembly\dl3\1ed1f335\00d7b454_9450ca01\BArcodingIm­aging.DLL

Because of this, the breakpoint at the method (ReadBarcode) in the class library is not reached: **clsBarcodeImaging.cs**

Comment: Maybe the answer to these questions may help you find an alternative:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191192/recommend-an-open-source-net-barcode-reader-library
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604233/reading-and-decoding-pdf-417-barcodes-stored-in-an-image-or-pdf-file-from-within
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613881/how-to-read-a-value-from-a-barcode-reader

Comment: If you hit continue on that popup, it should eventually display the exception for you.  If not, put a try-catch around the offending code and log the exception somewhere.

Comment: Actually,that Pop Up get disappear on click on 'OK' shown on this and when i put try catch,it does not go into catch and dont display any exception.Actually the method which i am using that is (ReadBarcode),when i clickon it to go into its definition,then it goes into metadata.So pls tell what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try zxing.net plugin  it help to decode barcode from bitmap image
https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net
or try 
NueDynamicsBarcode sdk